# How does Phantom Steed behave in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mount

The description of the 3rd-level Wizard ritual spell [Phantom Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantom-steed) reads:

> The creature uses the statistics for a riding horse, except it has a speed of 100 feet and can travel 10 miles in an hour, or 13 miles at a fast pace. When the spell ends, the steed gradually fades, giving the rider 1 minute to dismount. The spell ends if you use an action to dismiss it or if the steed takes any damage.

I'm unclear on how Phantom Steed behaves, especially in combat:

1. If the steed takes enough damage to be killed, does it die immediately or does it continue existing for 1 minute?
2. For the 1 minute while it is fading, can the steed be ridden as normal?
3. Can the steed perform the Dodge, Disengage, or Dash actions as a regular mount can?
4. Can the steed pull a wagon or other vehicles?
5. If not ridden, does the steed block the space it is on? If not, is the space it occupies considered difficult terrain?

Comment: In general, you should avoid editing your question to change it or ask new sub-questions after it's already been answered. In addition, [you should generally ask one question per post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what) (or one closely connected group of questions). Currently, questions #1 and #2 are closely related to one another, but #3 is a totally different question, as is #4, and so is #5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It will fade over 1 minute. [The spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantom-steed) says "The spell ends if you use an action to dismiss it or if the steed takes any damage." and "When the spell ends, the steed gradually fades, giving the rider 1 minute to dismount."
2. No, once the spell ends its effects end to. The fading is an extra effect that lasts 1 minute, this does not extend any other effects.
3. Yes, it behaves as per the [Mounted Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat) rules.
4. Yes, it "uses the statistics for a riding horse".
5. It blocks the space. The Phantom Steed is a "Large quasi-real, horselike creature" and "uses the statistics for a riding horse".

Comment: @jgn Thank for your answer! I added a new question (#2), could you answer it too?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I added a point about that one for you!

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil "giving the rider 1 minute to dismount" suggests that the horse does not drop dead / fall prone. Also, it was never alive, so it cannot die, it just fades out of existence.

Comment: @Szega the steed is a creature, so I would assume it can die.

Comment: @GuillaumeF.You are right. Reconsidering, it seems that if killed in one blow, it would die, fall prone and the body will fade away. Interesting.

Comment: @Szega Correct, regardless as to whether the steed remains alive, becomes unconscious, or dies, the spell will end and the body will fade over 1 minute.

Comment: @jgn when the spell ends, the rider is given 1 minute to dismount. Doesn't this imply that the rider can remain mounted for 1 minute after the steed lost all HPs?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. The rider has one minute after it takes ANY damage. If it loses ALL it's statistically-identical-to-a-riding-horse HP it presumably has the same behavior as a riding horse that does so, which is to be dead. The rider still has the rest of the minute to dismount its phantom corpse.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. There are 2 cases to consider: Case 1: If the mount takes damage, but not enough to reduce it to 0hp, then the rider remains mounted as the steed fades out over 1 minute. Case 2: If the steed takes enough damage to kill it, then it will fall prone, then as per the mounted rules "you can use your reaction to dismount it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it." You cannot remain mounted on the dead/dying fading steed.

Comment: @BenjaminOlson If the steed is reduced to 0hp then it will immediately fall unconscious and thus prone (regardless if it suffers instant death). Then as per the mounted combat rules "you can use your reaction to dismount it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it."

Comment: @jgn Good point. I was being a bit goofy to emphasize the point that it can spend part of that minute before fading being dead (or unconscious) but it definitely wasn't an actual accurate description of mounted combat rules.

Comment: In response to your answer to number 2: "When the spell ends, the steed gradually fades, giving the rider 1 minute to dismount." But then you say that the rider cannot actually ride the mount if the spell ends. Those seem directly contradictory

Comment: @Medix2 When a spell ends, its effects ends too. Once the spell has ended you cannot control the mount. This spell has a special effect that begins when the spell ends, causing the steed to fade over 1 minute giving you time to dismount. If you can go in to more detail about what part of this is confusing then I can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: I would say no to #4. A steed is a animal you ride. The spell isn't phantom horse or summon horse, it's phantom STEED. And the wording doesn't say you may use it as a horse, it says you or a creature you designate may ride it.

Comment: @EmronBardsley The Phantom Steed is a Large sized creature which "uses the statistics for a riding horse" (i.e. a beast with a strength of 16). Its normal carrying capacity is thus 480 lbs, but chapter 5 of the PHB (Mounts and Vehicles) says "An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle." So since a riding horse is most certainly an animal, the steed should be able to pull 2400 lbs, including the weight of the vehicle.